# IsNullOrEmpty' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static FormattedString AddParagraph(this FormattedString formattedString, string text)
    {
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return formattedString;
        else
        {
            formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("555555") });
            return formattedString;
        }
    }
```

But it's telling me: The name 'IsNullOrEmpty' does not exist in the current context

Can anyone give me advice on how I can check if this string is "" or it has something other than ""?

Comment: That is a static method of the string type, so use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be **[`string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IsNullOrEmpty_System_String_)**

**EDIT**
You need to use the above because string.IsNullEmpty() is a static method that you can use it inside your static method.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use `IsNullOrEmpty` standalone, you could use C# 6’s [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) feature. You just need to add the relevant `using` to your code:

```
using static System.String;
```